# Show context menu only on sites from permissions list

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I making extension based on page_action.
I'd like to add context menu for pages where page_action available.

So manifest.json

```
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":["http://*.site.com/*/*/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=*"],
        "js":["site_cs.js","jquery-1.10.2.js"],
        "css":["site_cs.css"]
    }
],

"permissions":[
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "contextMenus",
    "http://www.site.com/*"
]
```

A call on site_cs.js to display page_action icon

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "show" });
```

Then on eventPage.js I display page_action icon for current filtered tab.
Also as current page is filtered already by content script permissions I guess I can show context menu here

```
var menuItem = {
    "id": "addTask",
    "title": "Add Task",
    "contexts":["all"]
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "show") {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
            chrome.pageAction.show(tabs[0].id);
        });
        chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
           chrome.contextMenus.create(menuItem);    
        });
    }
});
```

But the issue is I see this context menu on the all tabs.
What's wrong with my code?